# Reinstall Office for Mac 2011

Tags: macbook-pro, ms-office, install

I downloaded Office 2011 to my old computer that crashed and no way to retrieve HD contents. I lost everything. Now I have a new computer MacBook Pro and I have the key number that I had printed out before.  Maybe this sounds dumb but can I download the program again on this new computer since I have the key number? How do I do it?

Answer (score 2):

To re-download Office for Mac 2011 go to Microsoft's [Office for Mac 2011 Download Site](https://www7.downloadoffice2010.microsoft.com/macdl/registerkey.aspx?culture=en-us&ref=macdl) and after choosing a language version, entering your serial number, and completing the CAPTCHA you should get a link.

In the common browsers like Safari, Firefox and Google Chrome the site looks like scam but it seems to be legit.